# Copy all formulas when inserting new row in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to copy all formulas when inserting a new row in the Excel worksheet. I have some calculation formulas and I am taking some values from another Excel file.

Formulas I am using in this Excel worksheet are as follows:

1. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,'list.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$4:$L$261,3,FALSE),"")`
2. `=IFERROR(G6*F6,"")`

I googled for a solution.  I got 2 ideas.

one to make a table with these data.
I tried this one. Formula no:1 worked perfectly. But 2nd formula didn't copy to next line.

The second one to use a VBA code. which works only one time. When open excel next time I have to create VBA code again. also, it needs to click in between cells to create next row.

I want to create a new row when right click on the sl no(leftmost column) and click "insert".

Please help.

Comment: If you say *"But 2nd one didn't work."* please describe what exactly didn't work. Did the formula not copy at all or did it show a wrong result?

Comment: ...same with *"works only one time"*.  What did you try, and why didn't it work? Did you get an error?   Also, where did you place the VBA code that was missing when you re-opened the file?  ..it's likely either in a different workbook, or in a different module of the correct workbook. See "[Where to put the VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WhereToPutTheCode.aspx)".

Comment: @Pᴇʜ =IFERROR(G6*F6,"") this formula didn't copy to next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry im new in SO but i want to help you:

1. You using conditional blocking for example : `$A$4:$L$261`
2. `=IFERROR(G6*F6,"")` doesnt copy anything
3. In VBA you got function `PasteSpecial` whats copeing a formulas from
   cell, here some ex. of using that:

   ```
   With Worksheets("YourWorksheet_name")
     .Range("Your_cell_input").Copy
      .Range("Your_cell_output").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
   End With
   ```
4. If i good understand u want a maro what pasting a forulas when new rod is added. I recommend to use something like this:

   Let's make a demo that You have formulas on colmn C to copy that(its affecting column A)

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Column = ActiveCell.Column Then
       refRow = Target.Row - 1
       thisRow = Target.Row
       Range("C" & refRow).Copy Range("B" & thisRow)
     End If

   End Sub
   ```
5. Anyway please add some more code what u have or screenshoots what u expecting